# Unable to register executables on 64 core machine having Windows Server 2008 R2 as OS

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

We have a combination of 32-bit Dlls/Exe and 64-bit Dll's/Exe in our setup  .  When we try to register these Dll's/EXE on a  64 core machine having Windows Server 2008 R2 as OS ... we are unsuccessful . When the same machine is reconfigured to use a 4-core , the registeration is successful . What could be the reason ?

Comment: What do you mean "unsuccessful"? How do you register them? What error code is returned?

Comment: @Maximus the error is "Terminated Process(Timeout)"